# why does my flash-animation reset when i move the mouse?

Tags: flash, mouseevent, movieclip

I have 2 overlapping movieclips on the stage. Both are instances of the same movieclip, but with different names. One bigger then the other, due to a magnifying effect. (I have tried to out-rule that code by the way, so its not that).

The intention is to make both movieclips play when the mouse is over the stage and then stop as the mouse leaves the area. Seems simple and I have done that alot of times with other animations.

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hideStuff);
var stageRunning:Boolean = new Boolean(false);

function hideStuff(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (bigAnimation_mc.currentFrame == 1)
{
    bigAnimation_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    smallAnimation_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
    stageRunning = true;
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hideStuff);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, showStuff);
}
}

function showStuff(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (stageRunning)
   {
    bigAnimation_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    smallAnimation_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    stageRunning = false;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hideStuff);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, showStuff);
}
}
```

If someone could help me figure where the loose end is, you would make me very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` happen whenever the mouse moves over or out of anything contained in the stage. Instead use `ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT`.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer... but after changing the MOUSE_OVER and and MOUSE_OUT with ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT, the animations doesn't start playing at all..

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but maybe it's not supported on the stage? Try wrapping everything in another display object and putting the ROLL events there, or preferably look in the docs for a specific event that occurs if the pointer is moved on/off the stage/movie.